# blockui on blockui

Tags: jquery, blockui

I tried to put a blockui on top of another blockui, and it works (provided the baseZ value is higher for the second blockui of course)

The problem is when I want to close the top-most blockui with the $.unblockUI(); call, both close.

Is there a way to set a namespace or context? I did not find anything related so far on the web.

Comment: I've used this technique and it works like a charm in Opera, FF, Chrome, Safari and even IE9, but it does not work at all on IE8. Can anyone confirm that it's working on IE8? Maybe there's something wrong with my code, but before I start digging I want to make sure it's not a IE bug.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing specifics, I assume you are calling full page $.block() and $.unblock().

On the second blockUI, don't make it a full page (default) block but instead assign it to the specific DIV or jqModal dialog or whatnot that you show on the first blockUI.

You can then control the block/unblock specific to the second.

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#test') });

$('#test').block( { message: $('#test2') } );
$('#test').unblock(); 

$.unblockUI();
```